# Is there a way to reload an API every X seconds/minutes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

So I'm working on a tkinter gui for my raspberry pi 3 and i've some information coming through an API call, the thing is, i need to restart the system before it will update the api. I would like to have the API update automatically every X seconds or X minutes.
I hope you understand what i'm trying to tell you. Here is the code for the API call

```
    r2 = requests.get(' http://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
    advice_result= r2.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
import requests

def reloadapi():
    threading.Timer(5.0, reloadapi).start()
    r2 = requests.get(' http://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
    advice_result= r2.json()

reloadapi()
```

Here, your api is reloaded in every 5 seconds

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly but there is one other little problem maybe you could help me with. look at my latest answer please

Comment: you should try returning something from the function like return advice_result....see my another answer

Comment: and bro rate my answers @DanielSaggo

Answer (score 0):

```
def reloadapi():
    threading.Timer(5.0, reloadapi).start()
    r2 = requests.get(' http://api.adviceslip.com/advice')
    advice_result= r2.json()
    return advice_result
```

try this

Comment: where exactly are you using this code? and what value do you want in labelfield?

Comment: I’m usinfg it in the class frame for page 3. I want it to return the api in form of a label

Comment: try storing the returned value into a variable and then use it accordingly, and sorry i'm new to programming and just know basics of python, dont know much about tkinter